# Typo3 : Missing root page icon in page Tree (Typo3 Version 9.5.1)

Tags: typo3

I setup Typo3 9.5.1 in live server.

Root page icon is missing, like you can see:

[image: Attachment]

N.B.: It's working fine in my local:)

Comment: I’ve just [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still need to add additional information for your question to be solvable.

Comment: Use browser inspector, is the an error the in console? Maybe it is a missing icon. Else edit the rootpage and set: behaviour>use as root page?

Comment: Did you check .htaccess? It might be possible image file is not accessible check file permission as well.

Comment: I have checked everything but still icon missing